# How to align and center standalone amsmath equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, align, amsmath, standalone

I had this code produce the following document. I wanted to align a few things.
Particularly under the "degree sequence" heading:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %%%%% SNIP %%%%%
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
        \begin{math}
            $degree sequence$\\
            $e=\{2,2,2,2,2\}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c=\{2,2,2,2,2\}$\\
            \delta(e)=2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \delta(c)=2\\
            \Delta(e)=2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Delta(c)=2\\
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
            \alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},\ \ \alpha(e_{2})=c_{3},\\
            \alpha(e_{3})=c_{5},\ \ \alpha(e_{4})=c_{2},\\
            \alpha(e_{5})=c_{4},\ \ \alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},\\
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
            $e_{1}\to{}e_{2}\to{} e_{3}\to{}e_{4}\to{}
            e_{5}\to{}e_{1}\\
            $c_{1}\to{}c_{3}\to{} c_{5}\to{}c_{2}\to{}
            c_{4}\to{}c_{1}\\
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
        \end{math}    
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

So I tried to use the align package to align it, butit kind of sent everything out of wack:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %%%%% SNIP %%%%%
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
            degree sequence\\
            e = \{2,2,2,2,2,2\} c = \{2,2,2,2,2,2\}\\
        \begin{align*}
            \delta(e) & = 2 & \delta(c) & = 2\\
            \Delta(e) & = 2 & \Delta(c) & = 2\\
        \end{align*}
        \begin{math}
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
            \alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},\ \ \alpha(e_{2})=c_{3},\\
            \alpha(e_{3})=c_{5},\ \ \alpha(e_{4})=c_{2},\\
            \alpha(e_{5})=c_{4},\ \ \alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},\\
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
            $e_{1}\to{}e_{2}\to{} e_{3}\to{}e_{4}\to{}
            e_{5}\to{}e_{1}\\
            $c_{1}\to{}c_{3}\to{} c_{5}\to{}c_{2}\to{}
            c_{4}\to{}c_{1}\\
            \rule[0cm]{200pt}{0.5pt}\\
        \end{math}    
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Is there a way around this or am I stuck with it. I know it's only a minor thing, but it would be nice to have more control.

Comment: `align` is not a package and could you please elaborate on how you compile your codes? When I run pdflatex on the first one, I receive errors.

Comment: please make your mwe compilable. it has many errors (`There's no line to end`)

Comment: @mormot I used overleaf to compile it. Here's a read only link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qprgxcqtmppf and here's one anybody can edit:
https://www.overleaf.com/2177493499cghwsymwvdst

Comment: @Zarko If you see errors that you know how to fix, you're welcome to. I'm pretty new to LaTeX and I've done my best. If it has errors, I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was the only way I could think of to do it, without ending and beginning and dropping the indent back and forth for two words seemed like an annoyance. But it works is the main thing. It's not really the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, it seems to be working. There are a couple of answers already. I don't know what to tell ya. Sorry.

Comment: yes sure but as those answers show the math environment _was_ the issue (and both answers remove it), however I'll delete the comments as they don't really  help other readers,

Comment: @tjt263 Very nice :-) question. My memories of graph theory.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks. Am I on point? I'm brand new to it. Just started taking an intro to crypto class and it came up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so they did. that's weird I thought it was THE way to do it.

Comment: @tjt263 Very good and good lucky :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `tabular`:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{degree sequence}\\
$\begin{aligned}
& e=\{2,2,2,2,2\} \\
& \delta(e)=2 \\
& \Delta(e)=2 \\
\end{aligned}$ &
$\begin{aligned}
& c=\{2,2,2,2,2\} \\
& \delta(c)=2 \\
& \Delta(c)=2
\end{aligned}$ \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  $\begin{aligned}
  \alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1}, & \alpha(e_{2})&=c_{3},\\
  \alpha(e_{3})&=c_{5}, & \alpha(e_{4})&=c_{2},\\
  \alpha(e_{5})&=c_{4}, & \alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1},
  \end{aligned}$%
} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  $\begin{array}{@{} c *{5}{@{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{}} }
  e_{1} & \to & e_{2} & \to & e_{3} & \to & e_{4} & \to & e_{5} & \to & e_{1} \\
  c_{1} & \to & c_{3} & \to & c_{5} & \to & c_{2} & \to & c_{4} & \to & c_{1}
  \end{array}$%
} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a different alignment for the “degree sequence” block:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{degree sequence}\\
$\begin{gathered}
  e=\{2,2,2,2,2\} \\
  \begin{aligned}
  \delta(e)&=2 \\
  \Delta(e)&=2
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ &
$\begin{gathered}
  c=\{2,2,2,2,2\} \\
  \begin{aligned}
  \delta(c)&=2 \\
  \Delta(c)&=2
  \end{aligned}
\end{gathered}$ \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  $\begin{aligned}
  \alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1}, & \alpha(e_{2})&=c_{3},\\
  \alpha(e_{3})&=c_{5}, & \alpha(e_{4})&=c_{2},\\
  \alpha(e_{5})&=c_{4}, & \alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1},
  \end{aligned}$%
} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  $\begin{array}{@{} c *{5}{@{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{}} }
  e_{1} & \to & e_{2} & \to & e_{3} & \to & e_{4} & \to & e_{5} & \to & e_{1} \\
  c_{1} & \to & c_{3} & \to & c_{5} & \to & c_{2} & \to & c_{4} & \to & c_{1}
  \end{array}$%
} \\
\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i really appreciate having this alternative. i like how you reduced the whitespace too.

Comment: I just noticed it doesn't actually line it up perfectly. Probably because the glyphs aren't a fixed width. Still looks pretty good though.

Comment: @tjt263 I guess you were referring to the bottom lines: fixed.

Comment: I didn't notice that one. I meant the `δ(e)=2`, `Δ(e)=2`, etc. That's the part I was trying to align mostly. It's still pretty good. Better looking than what I had.

Comment: @tjt263 I added a different version.

Comment: You might have nailed it here. It's between you and @marmot. I can't decide. How can I choose just one! They're both perfect answers.

Comment: Actually if you have time could you do one more; so the *`e`s, `c`s, `=`s,* & *`δ`s/`Δ`s* line up on all 3 rows? Or is that stupid. I'll experiment with it when I'm back in front of a computer. I'm a perfectionist, I know.

Comment: @tjt263 Sorry, but it makes very little sense to try and align things that are unrelated to each other.

Comment: it's a personal preference regarding aesthetics. For instance, I've been trying to line up all the = signs. The ones prefixed with δ/Δ and α. So they're in neat columns. Been experimenting but can't get it right. It's not that important, but it's frustrating that I can't change it with ease.

Comment: @tjt263 Aligning the = in the degree sequence block would make for a very unbalanced appearance. Those symbols are very loosely related. Even more loosely are symbols in different blocks.

Answer (score 3):

`align` and `alignat` allow you to align. And you can put things in a node which has the same width as the figure.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Bullet/.style={circle,draw,fill=black,scale=0.75}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=top]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
 \node[Bullet,label=left :{$e_1$}] (E1) at (0,2) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=above:{$e_2$}] (E2) at (1,3) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=right:{$e_3$}] (E3) at (2,2) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=right:{$e_4$}] (E4) at (2,0) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=left :{$e_5$}] (E5) at (0,0) {} ;
 \draw[thick] (E1)--(E2)--(E3)--(E4)--(E5)--(E1) {} ;
\end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=right,xshift=4cm]
 \node[Bullet,label=left :{$c_1$}] (C1) at (0,2) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=above:{$c_2$}] (C2) at (1,3) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=right:{$c_3$}] (C3) at (2,2) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=right:{$c_4$}] (C4) at (2,0) {} ;
 \node[Bullet,label=left :{$c_5$}] (C5) at (0,0) {} ;
 \draw[thick] (C1)--(C3)--(C5)--(C2)--(C4)--(C1) {} ;
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\path let \p1=($(top.east)-(top.west)$) in
node[below=of top,align=center,text width=\x1]{
\rule[0cm]{\x1}{0.5pt}
degree sequence
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 e&=\{2,2,2,2,2\}& c&=\{2,2,2,2,2\}\\
 \delta(e)&=2 &\delta(c)&=2\\
 \Delta(e)&=2&\Delta(c)&=2
\end{alignat*}
\rule[0cm]{\x1}{0.5pt}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1},\quad&\alpha(e_{2})&=c_{3},\\
 \alpha(e_{3})&=c_{5},&\alpha(e_{4})&=c_{2},\\
 \alpha(e_{5})&=c_{4},&\alpha(e_{1})&=c_{1},
\end{alignat*}
\rule[0cm]{\x1}{0.5pt}
\begin{align*}
e_{1}&\to{}e_{2}\to{} e_{3}\to{}e_{4}\to{}
            e_{5}\to{}e_{1}\\
            c_{1}&\to{}c_{3}\to{} c_{5}\to{}c_{2}\to{}
            c_{4}\to{}c_{1}
\end{align*}
\rule[0cm]{\x1}{0.5pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice, thankyou

Answer (score 3):

with use of nested `array`:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
$
\begin{array}{@{}c @{}}
\begin{array}{cc}
\tikz\node[draw]{\includegraphics[width=31mm]{example-image-duck}};
                    & \tikz\node[draw]{\includegraphics[width=31mm]{example-image-duck}};\\
   \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$degree sequence$}               \\[1ex]
e =\{2,2,2,2,2\}    & c =\{2,2,2,2,2\}              \\
\delta(e)=2         & \delta(c)=2                   \\
\Delta(e)=2         & \Delta(c)=2                   \\
        \end{array}                                 \\    
    \midrule
\alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},\quad   \alpha(e_{2})=c_{3},    \\
\alpha(e_{3})=c_{5},\quad   \alpha(e_{4})=c_{2},    \\
\alpha(e_{5})=c_{4},\quad   \alpha(e_{1})=c_{1},    \\
    \midrule
e_{1}\to e_{2}\to e_{3}\to e_{4}\to e_{5}\to e_{1}  \\
c_{1}\to c_{3}\to c_{5}\to c_{2}\to c_{4}\to c_{1}  \\
    \midrule
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

instead your `tikzpicture` code i use example image.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a pretty good answer. +100 for the duck.